# What is the algorithm used by windows for certificate revokation (OCSP or CRL) and how to configure them?

Tags: c#, .net, security, ocsp

I'm using c# .Net framework for connecting to an HTTPS service and want to know how does windows check the certificate revokation. I've googled for hours and find that windows supports both OCSP and CRL. But the question is which one is used exactly? Is there any way to configure the used algorithm globally on the OS or from code (without using any third party library)?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior is:

- If OCSP is configured in certificate, OCSP is used.
- If OCSP fails, CRL is attempted.
- If CRL fails, a `RevocationOffline` error is raised. Application decides how to react to this error.

This was a very-very simple explanation. For better understanding of how revocation checking in Windows works, I would suggest to read these articles:

- [Windows XP: Certificate Status and Revocation Checking](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4954.windows-xp-certificate-status-and-revocation-checking.aspx)
- [Certificate Revocation Checking in Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee619730(v=ws.10))

Comment: Thank you so much @Crypt32. But is there any way to configure them in the code?

Comment: What exactly you want to configure?

Comment: I want to configure the used standard; for the example to say just use the CRL.

Comment: You can make revocation checking settings only when you application performs certificate validation. When you delegate revocation checking to operating system, you cannot modify OS behavior from your code.

Answer (score -1):

It generally depends on the certificate issuer as to what mechanism it supports . However if your application is trusting any certificate then certificate revocation should to be checked and I will suggest to use OCSP . Some drawbacks of CRL are outlined below

- CRL Can create a large amount of overhead, as the client has to search through the revocation list. In some cases this can be 1000's of lines long.
- CRLs are updated periodically every 5-14 days. Potentially leaving the attack surface open until the next CRL update.
- generally speaking If the client is unable to download the CRL then by default the client will trust the certificate. This is true for most of the popular browser applications.

Comment: last statement is completely wrong. Offline revocation error handling is strictly application-specific. There is no default behavior for offline revocation.